# Negation predicate not/2 for SAT Solver in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, sat, negation

I'm writing a SAT Solver in Prolog. Here's what I've been able to come up so far:

```
cst(true).
cst(false).

is_true(cst(true)).
is_false(cst(false)).

and(A,B) :- 
    is_true(A),
    is_true(B).

or(A,B) :-
    is_true(A),
    is_false(B).
or(A,B) :-
    is_false(A),
    is_true(B).
or(A,B) :-
    and(A,B).

% not(A) :-
```

I'm stuck on the not/1. Can anyone give me a clue?

Note that I'm not using Prolog's negation for the interpretation of the logical negation. So I implemented a second predicate is_false(+F) instead, which is true if the formula F is false.

Edit: I meant not/1 in the title, not not/2!

Comment: SWISH tells me "head_build_in", so I can't use 'not' as the name?

Comment: ah yes, not is a keyword, you have to use another name for the predicate

Comment: Alright, the program seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: do you plan to run something like and(A,or(B,nott(C)))?

Comment: In the example, they pose the query: ?- is_true( or(not(and(cst(true), cst(false))), cst(false)) ). and get true. I get false with my own program. Did I mess up somewhere? I think I misunderstood the task a bit. Apparently is_true(F) is what they wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your idea was good but there was no possibility to nest your terms. The solution was to use a predicate like the "Interpretation" in formal logic: you drag your `is_true` or `is_false` through the whole term:

```
is_true(cst(true)).
is_true(and(A,B)) :-
    is_true(A),
    is_true(B).
is_true(or(A,B)) :-
    is_true(A),
    is_false(B).
is_true(or(A,B)) :-
    is_false(A),
    is_true(B).
is_true(or(A,B)) :-
    is_true(A),
    is_true(B).
is_true(not(A)) :-
    is_false(A).

is_false(cst(false)).
is_false(and(A,B)) :-
    is_true(A),
    is_false(B).
is_false(and(A,B)) :-
    is_false(A),
    is_true(B).
is_false(and(A,B)) :-
    is_false(A),
    is_false(B).
is_false(or(A,B)):-
    is_false(A),
    is_false(B).   
is_false(not(A)) :-
    is_true(A).
    
?- is_true( or(not(and(cst(true), cst(false))), cst(false)) ).
true.

?- is_true( or(not(and(cst(true), cst(true))), cst(false)) ).
false.    

?- is_false( or(not(and(cst(true), cst(true))), cst(false)) ).
true.

?- is_false( or(not(and(cst(true), cst(false))), cst(false)) ).
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didnt quite understand why nesting wasn't possible with my code. I think I'm missing some core prolog ideas.

Comment: Do you have a logic background like a lecture or are you doing this for school?